# Exception in a task not causing the application to crash

Tags: c#, task

I am new to Task Parallel Library. I know that exceptions in foreground and background threads work in the same way i,e they propagate to the main thread and crash the application(if not handled). But, I am seeing a different behaviour while using tasks. When am exception occurs in a Task it just ends its execution without crashing the application or other tasks. If I am not wrong, a Task uses a background thread so the exception should be propagate to the Main thread and crash like a normal Background thread.

```
public static void Foo()
{
  throw new Exception("Blahh");
}
static void Main()
{
   Task t = Task.Run(()=>Foo());
   Thread.Sleep(500);
   Console.WriteLine("Main");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `Wait()` your `Task`. If a task has a result one can access `Result` property that calls `Wait()`. Note that an exception will be `AggregateException` and original exceptions will be in its `InnerExceptions` collection.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Example1();
            Example2();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Main");
        }

        public static void Example1()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Example1");
                Task t = Task.Run(() => Foo());
                t.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                foreach (var ex in e.InnerExceptions)
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void Example2()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Example2");
                Task<string> t = Task.Run(() => { Foo(); return "Task result"; });
                string result = t.Result;
                Console.Write(result);
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                foreach (var ex in e.InnerExceptions)
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void Foo()
        {
            throw new Exception("Blahh Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code to

```
public static void Foo()
{
  throw new Exception("Blahh");
}
static async Task Main()
{
   Task t = Task.Run(()=>Foo());
   Thread.Sleep(500);

   await t;

   Console.WriteLine("Main");
}
```

What you do now is you run a fire-and-forget task. So you actually say, I don't care about the result (even the exception).

When you `await` a task you say you want to know the result of the task.
In this case you do it to know if the task completed successfully (or threw an exception).

Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await#exceptions

Comment: Entry point can't be of type `Task`. Neither it can't be `async`.

Comment: It is a new language feature since C# 7.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main)

Comment: Thanks Tom. Its a nice explanation. Also, the simple wait will also do the same thing. I am not sure using an await in the main will be helpful as it is blocking the main thread IMO. But, the main doubt is solved anyways.

Comment: @Tom Houben, That is true. It realy does.

Comment: Oh yes. It does too. I had to see the implementation to understand that. Thanks again.